# Field-specific error messages in Play Framework/Scala forms

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to customize the default error message "This field is required" when using the "nonEmptyText" constaint in the Scala form helper.

Here is an example that I want to customize:

```
  val form = Form(
    tuple("email" -> nonEmptyText, "password" -> nonEmptyText)
      verifying ("Invalid email or password.", result => result match {
        case (email, password) => {
          User.authenticate(email, password).isDefined
        }
      }))
```

Optimally in my conf/messages file I could provide a field-specific error:

```
error.email.required=Enter your login email address
error.password.required=You must provide a password
```

But in the worst case I would be happy with a wildcard message using the field name:

```
error.required=%s is required  
#would evaluate to "password is required", which I would then want to capitalize
```

I saw this %s expression in some Play 1.x documentation but it does not seem to work anymore.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to drop the usage of a `nonEmptyText` and use a simple `text` field with a custom validation:

```
tuple(
  "email" -> text.verifying("Enter your login email address", _.isDefined),
  "password" -> text.verifying("You must provide a password", _.isDefined)
)
```

You can then move a step further and exchange the `String` inside the `verifying` clause for a call to the `play.api.i18n.Messages` object:

```
tuple(
  "email" -> text.verifying(Messages("error.email.required"), _.isDefined),
  "password" -> text.verifying(Messages("error.password.required"), _.isDefined)
)
```

*Note that this is untested code, but it should point out the direction.*

Good Luck

Comment: Your code worked great. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!